# String length of SQL row

Tags: php, sql

I only want to print Reactie eigenaar: " . $bericht['reactie'] when there is content in the database, if it's empty, don't print anything.

```
print("<h2>Guestbook</h2>");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT gebruikersnaam,recentie, reactie FROM gastenboek");
$stmt->execute();
$berichten = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($berichten as $bericht) {
    //print username
    print("<table class='guestbook'");
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td class='guestbooktitle'>Gebruikernaam: " . $bericht['gebruikersnaam'] . "</td>");
    print("</tr>");

    //print content
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td class='guestbookcontent'>Bericht: " . $bericht['recentie'] . "</td>");
    print("</tr>");
    print("</tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr>");
    //The owner can comment on the content else if the owner doesn't comment, I don't want Reactie Eigenaar to display
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT bericht FROM gastenboek");
    if ($stmt != 0) {
        print("<tr class='reactie'>");
        print("<td class=''>Reactie eigenaar: " . $bericht['reactie'] . "</td>");
        print("</tr>");
    } else {
        print("");
    }
    print("<br>");
}
print("</table>");
print("<br>");
```

Comment: `if(condition) == 'x'`

Comment: while clustered in a foreach?

Comment: I edited my comment before you posted that

Comment: Result  = Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in

Comment: `if (empty($bericht['reactie'])){...} else{...}` - *"if it's empty, don't print anything."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($bericht['reactie'] != '') {
    // print content that depends on $bericht['reactie']
}
```

Comment: `if (!empty($bericht['reactie']))` would be better than `if ($bericht['reactie'] != '')` since it would also catch `null`

Comment: @developerwjk But it will also catch `0`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
if ( strlen(trim($bericht['recentie'] ))) {
    print("<tr><td class='guestbookcontent'>Bericht: " . $bericht['recentie'] . "</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: Yes, as it's converted to 0/falsy.